# Comparing count of two different SQL tables

Tags: sql, presto

I have two tables A and B and am trying to compare their count like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a WHERE day = '2018-09-27' AS A,
COUNT(*) FROM table_b WHERE day = '2018-09-27' AS B;
```

I get an error when I do this as an intermediate step. 
My aim is to get the output as

```
day      table_a    table_b    difference    %difference
9/25/18    1            1             0          0
9/24/18    2            1             1          50%
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? What's the logic from `difference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.day, b.day) AS day
     , count_a
     , count_b
     , count_a - count_b AS difference
  FROM ( SELECT day, count(*) AS count_a FROM table_a GROUP BY day ) a
  FULL JOIN ( SELECT day, count(*) AS count_b FROM table_b GROUP BY day ) b
       ON b.day = a.day
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of doing this

```
select 
    A,
    B,
    A-B as difference
From
(
select
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a WHERE day = '2018-09-27') as A,
(select COUNT(*) FROM table_b WHERE day = '2018-09-27') as B
) Res
```